Google Cardboard Unity app double vision on iPhone 15 Pro
I have a Unity app that uses the Google Cardboard SDK. Support for the latest iPhone 15s was added in version 1.22.0. I have upgraded to that version, but I am experiencing a strange bug where the VR view looks like it has double vision. I have tried many theories, but nothing has worked... Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this bug?
The same app works completely fine on all other iPhones that I've tested. It's just the iPhone 15 Pro (and potentially the other iPhone 15 models as well). Here is a screenshot of my app on an iPhone 15 Pro.
Thanks so much for any ideas!

Can you confirm you have this issue? If it is only similar but not it, I recommend you post an issue on their GitHub.

No problem! Good luck with your project!

Here is a workaround: change the MSAA level to 0 on the camera's renderer.
Reference: https://github.com/googlevr/cardboard/issues/442

AFAICT it's only a workaround. The real fix is them resolving their bug. But in the meantime, if you can live without MSAA, you should be fine.

Yeah, it was a bit more complicated than that because we cannot live without MSAA.... So I had to add another Quality Setting that uses a different rendering pipeline asset with MSAA turned off which only the iPhone 15 device models use.
